# Is there any main method for finding norm of function in $L_1$ space?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Is there any main method for finding norm of function in $L_1$ space? For example :

> $f(x)$ = $\sin x$ in space $L_1[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please edit your question to make it more precise: you say *functional* but give an example of a *function*. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: i am sorry,i typed wrong. i meant function

Comment: Direct evaluation works for your example. $\|\sin\|_1 = \int_{-\pi}^\pi |\sin x| dx = 2 \int_0^\pi \sin x dx = 4$.

Comment: then for finding norm of function on $L_1[a,b]$ space, i need to integrate it from a to b ?

Comment: @Javidan: Using the definition of the norm doesn't hurt. In some contexts there may be other methods.  Make sure that you integrate the absolute value of the function, i.e., use the definition of the $L_1$ norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, if $f \in L^p(X)$, then $$\| f \|_p := \left(\int_X |f|^pd\mu\right)^{1/p}.$$

In this specific case case $p=1, X=[-\pi,\pi], f=\sin$, and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure we have (as @copper.hat points out)
$$
\|\sin||_1 = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\sin(x)|dx = 2\int_0^\pi \sin x dx = 4.
$$

That is, to find the norm of a *function* you literally just plug into the definition.